# Windows boot fails after plugging second HDD

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, uefi

There is an UEFI computer with SSD disk and Windows 8.1 installed on it. I'd like to add an HDD drive (non-empty, has some information, probably there was some old broken Windows on it too, but it was almost completely deleted).

After plugging in this device Windows boots normally, but second reboot fails completely, computer goes to infinite reboot.

Removing this HDD magically helps, Windows boots again as usual. After inserting the device everything repeats again: first boot runs well, second fails.

After the "first" boot (the only stage both HDD and SSD plugged) bcdloader says that default Windows to be boot is current:

```
Windows boot Manager
--------------------
igentifier {bootmgr}
device partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description Windows Boot Manager
locale ru-RU
inherit {globalsettings}
default {current}
resumeobject {b9e61d85-754a-11e2-8deb-80777c2fbbe8}
displayorder {current}
toolsdisplayorder {memdiag}
timeout 30

Windows Boot
-------------------
identifier {current}
device partition=C:
path \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description Windows 8
locale ru-RU
inherit {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence {b9e61d87-754a-11e2-8deb-80777c2fbbe8}
recoveryenabled Yes
isolatedcontext Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice partition=C:
systemroot \Windows
resumeobject {b9e61d85-754a-11e2-8deb-80777c2fbbe8}
nx AlwaysOff
bootmenupolicy Standard
useplatformclock Yes
```

Please, what can I do? I'm very new to UEFI, but I checked settings, Windows boot managed loader is selected by default, selecting SSD as default doesn't help, computer fails to boot even with SSD alone.

UPD. If not to use reboot after the "first" (successful with two disks) boot but always do shutdown -> power on everything works fine (since fastboot is enabled). It is a workaround, but it is quite hard to live without rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found not an ideal solution but an appropriate one.

The problem was solved when I converted the second HDD partition table from MBR to GPT (the SDD was GPT initially).

It looks like that UEFI prefers MBR over GPT besides settings. Maybe converting SDD's from GPT to MBR would works too.

P.S. I've spend hours trying almost everything I've found to make Windows bootable with GPT SDD and MBR HDD, including EFI partition re-creation, `bcdboot` and direct edit of BCD by `bcdedit` in three different places (`EFI partition/boot/BCD`, `EFI partition/EFI/Microsoft/boot/BCD`, `c:\boot\BCD`), using real Windows installation DVD instead of USB stick since there is an advice that Windows PE could fails to recognize BCD this case (Windows PE's `bcdedit` was unable to find BCD without using `/store`), physically swap HDD's and SDD's cables, even tried to boot up using `GRUB2` with no success, so I'm not sure if it is possible at all. Over the internet I haven't seen any single suggestion that MBR could be a problem, hope it'll help someone.